# Studies with inconsistent value formats in a systematic review

Tags: meta-analysis, systematic-review

I am conducting a systematic review and would like to report the mean of a value that is consistently reported in the studies I've included.

However, some studies report the value as a range (e.g., "the range of values is from X to Y") and others report a mean (e.g., "the mean of the value is X").

How would I report the value in my review? Would I only take the means of the reported means and exclude the ranges? Or is there a way to estimate means based on ranges?

Comment: You need to state what you do and why.  If you think the ranges or intervals were based on something like $\bar x\pm c$ then looking at the middle of the interval is reasonable.  But if you think something else was done, such as a reported probability interval based on logistic analysis (so if symmetric for log-odds then possibly very asymmetric at the probability level) then this could be inappropriate.